confuse about the remark of CW complex definiton
This is from defintion in Rotman algebraic topology.
Definition: A CW complex is an ordered triple $(X, E, \phi)$, where $X$ is a Hausdorff space, $E$ is a family of cells in $X$, and $ \phi =\{ \phi_e : e \in E \}$ is a family of maps, such that
$(1)$ $X = \bigcup \{ e : e \in E \}$ (disjoint union);
$(2)$ for each $k$-cell $e \in E$, the map $\phi_e : (D^k, S^{k-1}) \rightarrow (e \cup X^{(k-1)}, X^{(k-1)})$ is a relative homeomorphism;
$(3)$if $e \in E$, then its closure $\overline{e}$ is contained in a finite union of cells in $E$;
$(4)$ $X$ has the weak topology determined by $\{ \bar e : e \in E \}$.
The following is the remark for it.
Axiom $(2)$ says that each $k$-cell $e$ arises from attaching a $k$-cell to $X^{(k-1)}$ via the attaching map $\phi_e|_{S^{k-1}}$.
I don't know what idea that he want to tell us. What is the relationship between the $k$-cell $e$ with the $D^k\coprod_{\phi_e|_{S^{k-1}}}X^{(k-1)}$. What is the word"arise" in this context, does he means $e$(i.e $k$-cell) is isomorphic to $D^k\coprod_{\phi_e|_{S^{k-1}}}X^{(k-1)}$?

I believe this is just introducing new terminology. I don't think anybody really says a single cell "arises" this way (you'd just say the cell's attached via its attaching map), but statements like "$X^k$ arises from $X^{k - 1}$ by attaching $k$-cells" are totally standard. As for how the cell relates to the pushout, if I'm guessing Rotman's definitions correctly then $e$ identifies with $\operatorname{int} D^k \subset D^k \coprod_{\phi_e|_{S^k - 1}} X^{(k - 1)}$. Either way it's probably a good idea for you to look at how other authors define CW-complexes.

Also, this definition seems needlessly strict (if a relative homeo means what I think it means), specifically condition (2). As @BenSteffan mentions in the comment above, the interior of the disk $D^k \setminus S^{k-1}$ maps homeomorphically onto its image in the $(k-1)$-skeleton. But it's quite common to build CW-complexes where the boundary of the cell maps to the properly lower dimensional skeleton, e.g., all of $S^{k-1}$ mapping to a point, which is of course not a homeo.

To say a continuous function $f : (X,A) \to (Y,B)$ is a relative homeomorphism means precisely that it is continuous, $f(A) \subset B$, and $f \mid X-A$ is a homemorphism onto $Y-B$. So to say that $\phi_e$ as stated is a relative homeomorphism is exactly the same as other formulations of this clause of the definition of a CW complex.


Axiom $(2)$ says that each $k$-cell $e$ arises from attaching a $k$-cell to $X^{(k-1)}$ via the attaching map $\phi_e|_{S^{k-1}}$.

Wha does "arise" mean in this context?
$(2)$ says that the map $\phi_e : (D^k, S^{k-1}) \rightarrow (e \cup X^{(k-1)}, X^{(k-1)})$ is a relative homeomorphism. This means that $\phi_e$ maps $D^n \setminus S^{n-1}$ homeomorphically onto $(e \cup X^{(k-1)})\setminus X^{(k-1)}) = e$.
Now recall the definition on p.186 :  An $n$-cell $e^n$ (or simply $e$) is a homeomorphic copy of the open $n$-disk $D^n \setminus S^{n-1}$. Precisely in this sense $e$ arises as the homeomorphic image of $D^n \setminus S^{n-1}$ under the map $\phi_e$.
